# Responsive design on Windows phones

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am fairly new to an app Development. One of the things that I am struggling with is to make sure my app looks the same on devices with different screen sizes.

Here is the logic that I use:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        placeUI();
    }
```

The placeUI() method is a method where I measure the width and the height of the screen. From there for instance if I need to place my component 10% from the left I just multiply its x position on a coordinate by 0.1.

My question is - if its the standard way of making UI responsive to diffirent screen sizes or is there an easier way? Thank you!

Comment: If you set your margins in the XAML, a lot of this should "just work" for you out of the box, so how's this not working for you?

Comment: When you use Grids for example, you can define the rows and columns ...and then with Height and Width props you can do it adjustable for all screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Define page layouts with XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml) for an several techniques to use for responsive design. That page targets Universal Windows apps (Windows 10), but other than the RelativePanel and AdaptiveTriggers everything applies to Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime apps as well.

If you just want a lightly responsive design such as your example of placing an item at a constant 10% from the edge then you can set your layout in a Grid control with a column set to take 10% of the Window:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">This is 10% from the left</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

While this seems like a lot for a single item, it usually works out well for a typical layout with multiple elements.

For busier designs with many more controls you may want to move them around based on the size of the screen. 50% of a wide screen may be plenty for a given chunk of text while 50% of a narrow screen may be much too small for the same text. The app may want to switch from a horizontal layout on the wide screen to a vertical layout on narrow screens. The app can use visual states to move controls around or switch the controls completely (e.g. a GridView for wide screens and a ListView for narrow screens, both bound to the same underlying data).